# paswordless sqlplus using tnsnames.ora?

Tags: passwords, tnsnames

Is it possible to add your database username and password to a TNS entry in your tnsnames.ora file, so that you can run SQL*Plus without having to remember your username and password?

There's no need for lectures about security. I am perfectly aware of the risks, which are not an issue in the environment I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No via TNS entries however you can execute a script which has:

```
connect username/password
```

ie:

```
sqlplus /nolog my_connect_script.sql
```

If you're willing to invest more time into finding a "secure" way of storing your password you should research the Oracle Wallet.